# Why this code prints same thing 5 times?

Tags: c, string, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char name[50];

    char *top5[5] = {"user1" , "user2" , "user3" , "user4" , "user5"}; 

    int i ;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){

        printf("You entered the top5. Please enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);

        top5[i] = name;
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s" , top5[i]);
    } 
}
```

I want it to print `5` different names, because I used `5` different names while running the code. But it always prints the last name I used. It prints it `5` times. How can I fix that code?

Comment: Add the line `printf("%s\n", name);` at the end.  Hint: where do `top5[0]`, `top5[1]`, ... all point?

Comment: All `top5[i]` point to the same array, of course you will the the same value.

Comment: Add `printf("%s\n", top5[i]);` immediately after `top5[i] = name;` in the first loop, and run the program again.  You will see first the output that you expected, and then the last name you entered printed five times.  Think about what that must mean in terms of what's in the arrays.

Comment: or just learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and run step by step

Comment: `&name` in `scanf` should give a warning. Enable and don't ignore warning!

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

After this statement in the body of the loop

```
top5[i] = name;
```

each element of the array `top5` points to the first character of the array `name`.

Instead of using an array of pointers you could declare a two-dimensional character arrray.

The function scanf used with the format specifier `%s` is unsafe. Moreover the parameter shall be specified as `name` instead of `&name`.

You can use the standard function `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the original program can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   20

int main( void )
{
    char name[N];

    char top5[][N] = 
    {
        "user1" , "user2" , "user3" , "user4" , "user5"
    }; 

    const size_t M = sizeof( top5 ) / sizeof( *top5 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        printf("You entered the top5. Please enter your name: ");

        fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
        name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] ='\0';

        strcpy( top5[i], name );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        puts( top5[i] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you make *all* pointers of `top5` point to the *very same array*.

For a simple solution, make `top5` an array *of arrays*, and [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) into the  nested arrays.

Comment: can you please fix the code for me? I think you understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: @blackwater7 Because, to be blunt, you won't learn as much that way.

Answer (score -1):

`top5[i] = name`

is just wrong.

What you are looking for is `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`

> The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by dest. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.

In order to fix this problem, simply

`strcpy(top5[i], name)`

Moreover, to prevent buffer overflow you shouldn't use `scanf()`, instead `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)`

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an
>   `EOF` or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>   A terminating null byte (`\0`) is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

Comment: I put strcpy(top5[i], name); instead of top5[i] = name;

and i still have the problem. Now, after entering my name, program crashes.

Comment: This will result in undefined behaviour for writing to an immutable object (a string literal). Plus the problem if the source is longer than the destination array.